# Button's onClick property does not show my action

Tags: java, android

I was trying to program a simple calculator in Android Studio, only with plus, minus, times and divide functions. I am half-code in programming of "plus" function, which is triggered by clicking a button. Here is my code in MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public class Arithmetic {
    public void plus(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String numberOne = editText.getText().toString();
        String numberTwo = editText2.getText().toString();
        String result = numberOne + numberTwo;

    }
}}
```

Now I have two questions. Firstly, how do I make it to show `result` in `textView`? Secondly, `public void plus` is not showing in button's box onClick. Why? And how do I make it to show there?

I will be really thankful for every useful tip.

Comment: I;d recommend you read some elementary tutorials first and come back when done wit that. Otherwise it may be pretty ineffective to try to write any code w/o understanding what you are doing that for and why it should look like

Comment: @ArnaudPradier Can I ask, what courses do you find useful or are there any you would recommend me? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Firstly, how do I make it to show result in textView

```
int sum = (Integer.parseInt(numberOne)) + (Integer.parseInt(numberTwo));

String result = sum + "";
textView.setText(result); 

//or
textView.setText(sum + "");
```

> 2.Why public void plus is not showing in button's box onClick

```
<button
----
android:onClick = "plus"/>
```

and

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
onCreate().....

public void plus(View view){
//your button code here
}
```

No need to create a nested class for that!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, but you should learn some Android and Java basics before starting a project:

Remove the `onClick` property of your button in your xml file, it's better to use a `OnClickListener` (particularly if you are planning to use multiple buttons)

```
package com.example.arnaudpradier.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button calculBtn;
    EditText inputFieldOne;
    EditText inputFieldTwo;
    TextView showResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calculBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateBtn);
        inputFieldOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFieldOne);
        inputFieldTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFieldTwo);
        showResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);

        calculBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void makeAddition() {
        int firstValue = (Integer.parseInt(inputFieldOne.getText().toString()));
        int secondValue = (Integer.parseInt(inputFieldTwo.getText().toString()));
        String result = (firstValue + secondValue) + "";

        showResult.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int i = view.getId();

        if (i == R.id.calculateBtn) {
            makeAddition();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     EditText editText;
     EditText editText2;
     TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Arithmetic a = new Arithmetic();
    Arithmetic.plus();

}

public class Arithmetic {
    public void plus() {
        String numberOne = editText.getText().toString();
        String numberTwo = editText2.getText().toString();
        String result = numberOne + numberTwo;
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}}
```